# Need to extract the JSON in between result values and pass in the regular extraction

Tags: jmeter

I getting the JSON results as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQxdS.png)

In which i want to extract the values after Amz-Signature=9889872081660e079248ff5a793726868b7de264832aa698fc7d6af6fd8d2674",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing it in 2 steps:

1. First extract `thumbnailUrl` value using [JSON extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), something like:

   [image]

   the configuration is for example/demo purposes only, I need to see the full JSON in order to come up with the comprehensive [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query, if you cannot post it as it contains sensitive data check out [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) article
2. Then extract the `Amz-Signature` value from the `thumbnailUrl` variable using i.e. [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor):

   [image]
3. That's it, you should be able to use extracted value as `${Amz-Signature}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) where required.